# Collectors.groupingBy and mapping to construct a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Please take a look at the code below. My intention is to get a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` through the streams API by using groupingBy and mapping. The logic to employ to get this output map is by just grouping the contents of the ArrayList al and counting the number of times the same element occurs.

For instance, the element A occurs twice so I want to get a map with key as A and value as 2. Similarly for B I want to see B as key and 3 as value. I just dont quite know how to implement mapping Function for this. I was able to write the grouping. Can I get help completing the lambda where I have question marks (????).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("A");
    al.add("A");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("V");
    al.add("V");
    al.add("C");
    al.add("C");
    System.out.println(
             al.stream()
             .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), mapping(??????, toList()))));
}
```

Comment: You contradict yourself. First you say you want a Map<String, List<Integer>>. The you say that you want key as A and value as 2. 2 is not a List<Integer>.

Answer (score 2):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Long> keyCountMap = al.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Notice the use of the downstream collector to compute the count.

Comment: or for whatever reason they want the key to be an `Integer` then `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));` or `.collect(toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1, Math::addExact));`